# Flex, filter tree using ITreeDataDescriptor without reload and close all nodes

Tags: apache-flex, tree, filtering

working with flex 4 and implementing filtering using ITreeDataDescriptor.
Filtering worked as expected like the following code snippet

however, i am trying to create a on-demand type of filter where user would type in the search clause in a TextInput, and as the user types, the tree nodes would be filtered on the fly.

my implementation now is have user click on the search button and then reapply the dataDescriptor then reload the data. A big problem is that the whole tree collapses after setting the dataProvider again.

any suggestion on how the on-demand filter can be achieved?

```
var dataFilter:ServicePricingFilter = new MyFilter();
dataFilter.searchString = this.txtSearchKeyword.text;
this.treeService.dataDescriptor = new MyDataDescriptor(dataFilter);
this.treeService.dataProvider = getTreeData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looked at the post Florian mentioned.
on-demand filtering is done by using ITreeDataDescriptor and a filterFunction.
on keyup event of the search TextInput, call invalidateList() function on the tree.

see the source code provided for the following post
http://www.davidarno.org/2009/04/01/how-to-filter-all-nodes-of-a-flex-tree-component/

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't set the dataprovider every time but use insted the filterFunction property available for ListCollectionView classes (ArrayCollection, XMLListCollection,...)

Comment: this link sort of compared using dataDescriptor and filterFunction to filter the tree. I decided to go with dataDescriptor.

Comment: changing filterFunction and cal refresh function would probably make the tree collapsed and reload ? no?

Comment: I haven't tried it but looking at this blog post : http://www.davidarno.org/2009/04/01/how-to-filter-all-nodes-of-a-flex-tree-component/ , it seems that it is possible

Comment: thanks, i was just looking at that post actually :) will checkout the source code.

Comment: actually i was looking for how the "Preferences" panel is implemented in the Flash builder. Very good user experience in my opinion.